# In OpenVPN, is the signing CA the mechanism used to validate clients and servers to each other?

Tags: openvpn

Assuming bidirectional keypair authentication with valid certificates, such as dates, etc., no tls-crypt, no CRL and no checks for common names.

Is that also the reason for using a private CA, instead of a public one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just OpenVPN - this is how PKI works, period. Your processes trust the issuing CA, so that they can be presented a certificate that they haven't seen before, they can trust that it was issued by a CA they trust.